# How do I extract img src from a string in React Native?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, extract, expo

Here's how the string looks like:

```
<h2><p><p class="t-j">Sáng 07/12, TTTM Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả khai trương tại phường Cẩm Bình, TP Cẩm Phả, tỉnh Quảng Ninh, đem đến những tiện ích đồng bộ của hệ sinh thái Vingroup cùng nhiều trải nghiệm mới mẻ cho người dân địa phương.</p></p></h2><p class="t-j">Ngay từ 8h30 sáng, trước thời điểm khai trương, hàng nghìn người dân Quảng Ninh đã xếp hàng dài chờ được khám phá trung tâm mua sắm, ẩm thực và vui chơi giải trí hiện đại lần đầu tiên hiện diện tại "mỏ vàng đen" của Việt Nam. Chị Nguyễn Ngọc Hà (35 tuổi) chia sẻ khi xếp hàng cùng nhóm bạn:“Chúng tôi sống cách đây cả chục cây số, nhưng nghe tin khai trương là phải tới mua sắm ngay. Chưa bao giờ Cẩm Phả có một địa điểm hiện đại và đủ mọi thứ chúng tôi cần như thế". Để bắt kịp nhịp độ phát triển kinh tế chung của toàn tỉnh Quảng Ninh và nhu cầu đối với những dịch vụ chất lượng của người dân thành phố Cẩm Phả nói riêng, mô hình TTTM đáp ứng nhiều nhu cầu trong một như Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả đang trở thành một xu hướng mới tại các địa phương đang phát triển.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc">Người dân xếp hàng nô nức đợi giờ mở cửa TTTM Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Tòa TTTM Vincom hiện đại với vẻ đẹp tân cổ điển đã trở nên vô cùng quen thuộc với người dân trên mọi miền Tổ quốc như một chỉ dấu cho điểm đến uy tín, chất lượng và trọn vẹn trải nghiệm với mọi gia đình. Sở hữu 4 tầng nổi, tổng diện tích trên 46.000m2, Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả quy tụ gần 40 gian hàng đem đến hàng nghìn sản phẩm phong phú và đa dạng về chủng loại, mẫu mã đến từ nhiều thương hiệu uy tín trong nước và quốc tế.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh-1.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc">Không gian toàn cảnh bên trong TTTM Vincom đầu tiên tại Cẩm Phả</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Trong hàng dài khách hàng có không ít các bạn trẻ. Họ đến đây với mong muốn là những người đầu tiên "xông đất" các thương hiệu uy tín lần đầu tiên có mặt tại Cẩm Phả như Maxxsport, Boo, Anta, Narsis và Thế giới nước hoa... Dự kiến, không khí mua sắm sẽ tiếp tục sôi động từ nay cho đến Giáng sinh, năm mới và Tết âm lịch vì Vincom sẽ còn đem đến hàng loạt chương trình hấp dẫn vào cuối năm.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh-2.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc"> Nhiều thương hiệu thời trang lớn được giới trẻ đón chờ trong ngày đầu khai trương</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Siêu thị tiêu dùng VinMart rộng 1.600m2 hôm nay cũng không còn chỗ trống. Các bà nội trợ Cẩm Phả rất hồ hởi vì chưa bao giờ việc mua sắm các sản phẩm xanh, an toàn và tươi ngon cho bữa cơm gia đình lại dễ dàng như thế. Cánh đàn ông thì mải mê ngắm nghía, trải nghiệm các sản phẩm công nghệ, điện máy mới nhất tại Siêu thị Điện máy VinPro và tranh thủ mua sắm ngay trong đợt giảm giá này.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh-3.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc">Siêu thị hàng tiêu dùng VinMart và siêu thị điện máy VinPro mang đến những mặt hàng chính hãng, giá cả hợp lý cho người tiêu dùng</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Người Cẩm Phả rất tinh tế và cầu kì trong ăn uống. Để chiều lòng những thực khách “khó tính”, Vincom mang đến thế giới ẩm thực từ nhiều văn hóa thu nhỏ trong một TTTM. Từ những món gà Hàn Quốc hấp dẫn tại GuiGui, tới lẩu nướng hương vị Thái Lan - Thai BBQ rồi pizza Ý đặc sắc tại Pizza FC1,… Đặc biệt, lần đầu tiên Donchicken - thương hiệu gà rán đình đám Hàn Quốc, đã từng gây sốt cho giới trẻ tại nhiều thành phố lớn như Hà Nội, TP.HCM,… sẽ có mặt tại Cẩm Phả.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh-4.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc">Không gian ẩm thực mới mang đến nhiều lựa chọn cho khách hàng</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Thế giới vui chơi giải trí là thế mạnh của Vincom trên toàn hệ thống. Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả mang đến CGV Cinemas với phòng chiếu tiêu chuẩn quốc tế và Funny Kid, Funny Game rộng tới 900 m2 với các hoạt động vui chơi kết hợp giáo dục lành mạnh cho các em nhỏ. Đặc biệt, trong tuần lễ khai trương, Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả sẽ thực sự là điểm đến của người dân địa phương khi mang đến hàng loạt các chương trình âm nhạc hấp dẫn như: Đêm nhạc mừng khai trương vào tối 07/12 với sự xuất hiện của ca sĩ Lou Hoàng, “Vũ điệu Mầm Xanh” vào cuối tuần sau khai trương,... Không chỉ dừng ở đó, Vincom sẽ liên tục tổ chức nhiều chương trình vui chơi, hội chợ và giao lưu văn hoá trong dịp cuối năm để thực sự biến nơi đây trở thành điểm hẹn gắn kết và góp phần nâng cao chất lượng sống cho cộng đồng.</p>
<table class="FmsArticleBoxStyle ImageBox ImageCenterBox Border-1 image">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Images image "><img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh-5.jpg" alt="{keywords}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FmsArticleBoxStyle-Content image_desc"> Rất đông khách hàng chờ đợi được trải nghiệm rạp chiếu film đẳng cấp tại Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j">Với văn hoá phục vụ từ trái tim, 73 TTTM Vincom trên toàn quốc không ngừng nâng cao chất lượng dịch vụ và sản phẩm để mang đến cho khách hàng những trải nghiệm trọn vẹn nhất. Không chỉ có vậy, Vincom còn truyền đi thông điệp ý nghĩa bảo vệ môi trường qua các chiến dịch truyền thông nhân văn như "Hành trình xanh, trái tim xanh" nhằm nâng cao ý thức tiêu dùng xanh cho người tiêu dùng, góp phần xây dựng cộng đồng văn minh ở mỗi nơi minh hiện diện.</p>
<table class="phatngon" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="item-text">
<p class="t-j"><span class="bold">Chương trình khuyến mại nhân dịp khai trương tại Vincom Plaza Cẩm Phả</span></p>
<p class="t-j">·         Khách hàng có hoá đơn từ 500.000 đồng trở lên tại gian hàng bất kỳ sẽ nhận được một phiếu rút thăm trúng giải đặc biệt là điện thoại điện thoại Vsmart 6GB/64GB trị giá 3,7 triệu đồng.</p>
<p class="t-j">·         Khách hàng có hóa đơn từ 300.000 đồng trở lên tại VinMart có cơ hội bốc thăm trúng máy lọc nước Unilever Pure It Mineral Ro+ UV Ultima, bộ chảo, nồi đáy từ, bộ 5 hộp thông minh Kigi, vali cao cấp ABS 24 inch cùng nhiều quà tặng khác.</p>
<p class="t-j">·         Siêu thị điện máy VinPro dành tặng 100 ấm siêu tốc VinMart Home cho khách hàng có hóa đơn mua sắm từ 1 triệu đồng, 70 nồi cơm điện Sunhouse cho hóa đơn từ 3 triệu đồng và 20 bếp điện Sunhouse cho hóa đơn 5 triệu trở lên</p>
<p class="t-j">·         Thời trang Anta, Vitimex, Narsis, Medicare,… giảm tới 50% tất cả các sản phẩm</p>
<p class="t-j">·         Nhà hàng Lotteria giảm giá giờ vàng, Donchicken tặng đồ uống, giảm giá 10% cho hóa đơn 500k; nhà hàng Gui Gui đi 4 tính tiền 3</p>
<p class="t-j">·         Thông tin chi tiết xem thêm tại: https://www.facebook.com/vcpcampha/</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="t-j"><span class="bold">Minh Tuấn</span></p>
```

How do I extract the first img tag `<img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh.jpg" alt="{keywords}" />`'s src from the string above in React Native? Any suggestions? Thanks

I use react-native-rss-parser to parse an rss feed and the string above is from a `CDATA`, which is nested inside a `content` tag. However, the react-native-rss-parser I'm using doesn't support extracting  from a `CDATA` yet, which leads me to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't imagine a use case for this, but whatever. This has nothing to do with `react-native`, it's just string parsing in JS.

So, if you want to get just the first `img` tag, this can be achieved by using a combination of `indexOf` and `substring`.

```
const startingOfFirstImageTagIndex = htmlString.indexOf('<img')

// Get rid of everything until first img tag, so we can search for the ending with a new indexOf('/>')
const partialString = htmlString.substring(startingOfFirstImageTagIndex, htmlString.length);

const endOfFirstImageTagIndex = partialString.indexOf('/>');
const imageTag = partialString.substring(0, endOfFirstImageTagIndex + 2);
console.log(imageTag); // <img src="https://vnn-imgs-f.vgcloud.vn/2019/12/07/16/vincom-khai-truong-tttm-dau-tien-o-cam-pha-quang-ninh.jpg" alt="{keywords}" />
```

If you want to get all images from that string, you got to do something a little bit more complex than that, this is just a simple and quick solution on how to get the first image tag, without taking performance or stuff like that into account.